# How to connect to a bluetooth PAN of a specific device without Network Manager?

Tags: linux, networkmanager, bluetooth, bluez

I can not use the network manager tool.
I am able to pair with the bluetooth device. 
The Bluetooth GUI tools always use the network manager.

What alternatives do I have?
How can I configure my system to connect to a PAN of a certain device?
I read some articles about it. But there is no recent one. They are all around 10 years old.